Error when linking Libtorch with OpenFOAM: Two or more data types in declaration error, C++14
I am trying to link a custom library of (type of combustion class) OpenFOAM with Libtorch for a custom class. When I include some libtorch headers (for example: <torch/torch.h> ) I receive a series of errors:
/opt/openfoam7/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/className.H:40:34: error: two or more data types in declaration of ‘typeName_’
   40 |     static const char* typeName_() { return TypeNameString; }

/opt/openfoam7/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/typeInfo.H:72:19: error: ‘word’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘word_H’?
   72 |     virtual const word& type() const { return typeName; }

/home/sergen/torch/files/libtorch/include/c10/util/typeid.h:437:38: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘noexcept’
  437 |   static c10::string_view TypeName() noexcept {

/home/sergen/torch/files/libtorch/include/c10/core/TensorImpl.h: In member function ‘T* c10::TensorImpl::data() const’:
/home/sergen/torch/files/libtorch/include/c10/core/TensorImpl.h:1184:27: error: ‘TypeName’ is not a member of ‘caffe2::TypeMeta’
 1184 |         caffe2::TypeMeta::TypeName<T>(),

/home/sergen/torch/files/libtorch/include/c10/core/TensorImpl.h:1184:37: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
 1184 |         caffe2::TypeMeta::TypeName<T>(),

and so on. When I include it in another library, I receive no error and it is compiled with no errors or warnings. I am not a C++ guru, but, I am just modifying the files in Make folder (options&files) in OF to link it with torch, and the warnings are thrown right after.
I tried to include the torch header files in another class, which worked with no issues, however, I could not include the header file where exactly I needed them.
